# notification at a certain time everyday

Tags: android

Hi I'm new to Android. I want to notify the user everyday at a certain time. I tried to use AlarmManager fires up a Service, in this Service I set up a notification. My codes are below and they are not working right now:

My alarm service code:

```
public class MyAlarmService extends Service 
{

   private NotificationManager mManager;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
    {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() 
    {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
       super.onCreate();
    }

   @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
   @Override
   public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
   {
       Intent intents = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
       intents.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
       PendingIntent m_PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                getBaseContext(), 0, intents, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
       mManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);



       NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("My notification")
                .setContentText("Hello World!")
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND
                | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);

       mBuilder.setContentIntent(m_PendingIntent);

       mManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

My receiver code:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
       Intent service1 = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);
       context.startService(service1);

    }   
}
```

code in MainActivity:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent,0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, pendingIntent);
```

Right now, the notification will not show up after I set the time. Where is my problem?

Comment: Also, use `Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE` instead of `this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE`.  Since this is a static constant you can directly use the Context class to refer to it. You won't need the `@SuppressWarnings("static-access")` then :)

Answer (score 1):

You should override the `onStartCommand()` method in your Service in place of `onStart()`. The `onStart()` method is called only on pre Android 2.0 Platforms. On the later versions of Android, only the `onStartCommand()` is called.

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29).

Comment: So I just change onStart() to onStartCommand(), I see the example it returns START_STICKY, what is this?

Comment: Returning START_STICKY makes sure that the Service is never stopped by android until the app explicitly stops it.